# Scrolling credits text in Android

Tags: android, textview, scroll

I need to make a credits screen (`Activity`) in my game. It would be just a vertically scrolling text lines without any images. Scrolling is to be performed automatically and no user interaction is allowed. Just like movie credits that goes from bottom to top. After the last text line has disappeared above top of the screen, it should restart.

How do I do it? It is sufficient to just use `TextView` and animate it somehow? Or should I put that `TextView` into `ScrollView`? What would you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using this :-

```
    /**
 * A TextView that scrolls it contents across the screen, in a similar fashion as movie credits roll
 * across the theater screen.
 *
 * @author Matthias Kaeppler
 */
public class ScrollingTextView extends TextView implements Runnable {

    private static final float DEFAULT_SPEED = 15.0f;

    private Scroller scroller;
    private float speed = DEFAULT_SPEED;
    private boolean continuousScrolling = true;

    public ScrollingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup(context);
    }

    public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);
        setup(context);
    }

    private void setup(Context context) {
        scroller = new Scroller(context, new LinearInterpolator());
        setScroller(scroller);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        if (scroller.isFinished()) {
            scroll();
        }
    }

    private void scroll() {
        int viewHeight = getHeight();
        int visibleHeight = viewHeight - getPaddingBottom() - getPaddingTop();
        int lineHeight = getLineHeight();

        int offset = -1 * visibleHeight;
        int totallineHeight = getLineCount() * lineHeight;
        int distance = totallineHeight + visibleHeight;
        int duration = (int) (distance * speed);

        if (totallineHeight > visibleHeight) {
            scroller.startScroll(0, offset, 0, distance, duration);

            if (continuousScrolling) {
                post(this);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (scroller.isFinished()) {
            scroll();
        } else {
            post(this);
        }
    }

    public void setSpeed(float speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public float getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setContinuousScrolling(boolean continuousScrolling) {
        this.continuousScrolling = continuousScrolling;
    }

    public boolean isContinuousScrolling() {
        return continuousScrolling;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have you taken it from Matthias Kaeppler's "Android in practice"? I looking through this book right now and cannot find this source code snippet...

Comment: i dont remember now .. but if you are using it please give credit to the author

Comment: Boss, you save my day.

Comment: Thanks, what would be the best way to tell when it's done scrolling?