# TextView with a lot of line jumps (long height) doesn't fit

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-view

I have a text with a lot of linejumps, like this, but a lot bigger:

```
<string name="credits_big">
    Credits
    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
    Programmer
    \n\n
    Name
    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
    Music
    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
    Name
    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
    Programmer
    \n\n
    Name
    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
    Music
    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
    Name
<\string>
```

I'm animating the text up, to simulate a movie end credits, but at some point, the text is cut. It seems that TextView has a maximum height. How can I solve that?

This is the textview:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/creditsTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/credits_big"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/font"
    android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Hi @NullPointerException! There is an SO post that is solving the problem that you are trying to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029085/scrolling-credits-text-in-android. I think its possible that your solution might not work because of the way that android is drawing its graphics (e.g. it might not draw all the stuff that is in theory outside of the screen).. But in that post the answer contains a Class called `ScrollingTextView` you could use as a custom component in your XML even, just insert the class as a file in your project, and then use it in the XML instead of `TextView`

Comment: give me a thumbs up if you got it to work..

Comment: @SimonMayrshofer thanks, I tested before that solution but I need to know when the text has ended it's scroll and to pause and resume it. That solution doesn't support that.