# Anomalous WRAP_CONTENT behaviour

Tags: android, android-layout, android-wrap-content

It's supposed that `WRAP_CONTENT` does this:

> Special value for the height or width requested by a View. `WRAP_CONTENT` means that the view wants to be just large enough to fit its own internal content, taking its own padding into account.

But the reality is different

If you create a very long textview with a lot of height, bigger than the screen height, then, `WRAP_CONTENT` applied to the height of that textview has an erroneal behaviour, because limits the textview height to the screen height.

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Why `WRAP_CONTENT` has that erroneal behaviour?

How can you set to a view to have the size of it's content without being limited by the screen height?

Complete XML file (this is a screen for end titles of a game, the text will be animated up, because of that is hidden below the screen):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/creditsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/credits_big"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/font"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: How have you determined the `TextView` height is limited to the screen height - also, could you explain why this behaviour would be a problem? (Just because off the top of my head I can't imagine a situation where you'd care about how text is rendered when it is off screen).

Comment: @PPartisan this is a screen for end titles of a game, the text will be animated up. The text is much longer than the screen height, and I determine that is cutted at screen height estimating it, don't sure 100% but 99% yes.

Comment: May help: [Scrolling credits text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029085/scrolling-credits-text-in-android)

Comment: Also related: [Wrap_content view inside a ConstraintLayout stretches outside the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850966/wrap-content-view-inside-a-constraintlayout-stretches-outside-the-screen)

Comment: can you explain why did you put this - ' app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" '.  This line maybe the reason for unusual behaviour. 
instead try using ' app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" '.

Comment: @PavanVarma it's explained in the question, this is a screen for end titles of a game, the text will be animated up, because of that is hidden below the screen

Comment: It seems like the `TextView` height is limited to parents height, and `ConstraintLayout` is not a scrollable view - hence it is limited to its container (`FrameLayout`) height, which is limited to `Activity` height. 
If you want to simulate credit roll you should use some kind of Scrolling behavior (and maybe change `translationY` value). Check `TextView.getDesiredHeight()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get the true height of the text in the *TextView* and to resize the view to match.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mainLayout.doOnLayout {
            val tv = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.creditsTextView)
            val layout = tv.layout
            val lp = tv.layoutParams
            lp.height = layout.height
            tv.layoutParams = lp
        }
    }
}
```

Although this works, it makes me feel a little uneasy. You may want to look at other ways to accomplish your credits scroll.